# I want to check if 2 columns of any row from df1 == the same 2 columns of any row in df2

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 2 dfs like this

```
df1 <- data.frame("A" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "B" = c(10,20,30,40,50), "C" = c(6,7,8,9,11))
df2 <- data.frame("A" = c(10,4,30,20,50), "B" = c(1,40,3,7,5)), "C" = c(12,13,14,15))
```

I want to find if there is a row in df 1 that == a row in df2 for the columns A and B. You can see that `df1[4,1:2] == df2[2,1:2]`

I tried

```
for (i in 1:5){
  if (for (j in 1:5){
    df[i,1:2] == df2[j,1:2]})
    print("true")
}
```

But it gives me this error: `Error in if (for (j in 1:5) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: Your syntax in `if (for (j in 1:5){` is wrong, in `if (expression)` the expression needs to return one logical value (or if there are several, only the first one is used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can row-wise `paste` the values and check duplicates using `%in%` :

```
df1[do.call(paste, df1[1:2]) %in% do.call(paste, df2[1:2]),]
#  A  B C
#4 4 40 9
```

If you need only single `TRUE`/`FALSE` value

```
any(do.call(paste, df1[1:2]) %in% do.call(paste, df2[1:2]))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If you want to remove rows in `df1` which is present in `df2` you can use `anti_join` from `dplyr`.

```
dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('A', 'B'))
#  A  B  C
#1 1 10  6
#2 2 20  7
#3 3 30  8
#4 5 50 11
```

To get common rows you can use `semi_join`/`inner_join` :

```
dplyr::semi_join(df1, df2, by = c('A', 'B'))
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Can you tell me how I delete those rows that came as a result of your first code line?

Comment: @ApoloReis You can negate the condition? `df1[!do.call(paste, df1[1:2]) %in% do.call(paste, df2[1:2]), ]`

Comment: Sorry. My real problem is that in the original csv, I have cases in which line x has 4 40 as values in columns A and B respectively and line y has 40 4. l'm sorry for not displaying it as a table. I dont know how to do it here. So, when I execute this line you suggested, all the lines from the table that has equal columns values (just inverted) are deleted. I just wanted to delete the values 40 4 without deleting the 4 40 ones. Sorry if the explanation isn't clear

Comment: explaining better. I created one table (table 2) out of the original one (table1) and inverted the values in the columns A and B. So, when I execute this line you suggested, not only the 40 4 are deleted, but also the 4 40. I just want to delete the redundant information

Comment: @ApoloReis Why do you create a copy of the original table then? you can sort the two columns in the original table itself and remove the duplicated values from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can row bind columns A and B and use `anyDuplicated()`:

```
anyDuplicated(rbind(df1[1:2], df2[1:2])) > 0
[1] TRUE
```

If there are potential duplicates within data frames you'll need to make them unique first:

```
anyDuplicated(rbind(unique(df1[1:2]), unique(df2[1:2]))) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution returning the rows in `df1` and `df2`, columns `A` and `B`, that match.

```
res <- apply(df2[1:2], 1, function(y){
  apply(df1[1:2], 1, function(x) all(x == y))
})

which(res, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   4   2

w <- which(res, arr.ind = TRUE)
colnames(w) <- c('df1', 'df2')
w
#     df1 df2
#[1,]   4   2
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table` join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!df2, on = .(A, B)]
#   A  B  C
#1: 1 10  6
#2: 2 20  7
#3: 3 30  8
#4: 5 50 11
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame("A" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "B" = c(10,20,30,40,50), "C" = c(6,7,8,9,11))
df2 <- data.frame("A" = c(10,4,30,20,50), "B" = c(1,40,3,7,5), "C" = c(12,13,14,15, 15))
```